# Store bytes into correct wrapper

Tags: objective-c, c, byte

I am currently developing an app for iOS that parses libcap formatted files. For that, I need to implement the different protocols that will appaear in the files I parse. My problem is that I don't know how to store the different headers that I read. First I started by using C types such as **uint8_t**, **uint16_t**, etc. all these encapsulated into C structs.

For instance, here is the header of an ethernet packet :

```
#define ETHER_ADDR_LEN 6
typedef struct ethernet_hdr_s {
    uint8_t mac_dst[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];
    uint8_t mac_src[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];
    uint32_t tag;
    uint16_t ethertype;
    uint32_t crc;
}   ethernet_hdr_t;
```

Then I realized that this won't work since I'm going to have so many different sized header that this will be a real mess to work with. Then i thought of using uint8_t only and arrays. So my ethernet header transformed into something like :

```
#define ETHER_ADDR_LEN 6
typedef struct ethernet_hdr_s {
    uint8_t mac_dst[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];
    uint8_t mac_src[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];
    uint8_t tag[4];
    uint8_t ethertype[2];
    uint8_t crc[4];
}   ethernet_hdr_t;
```

But then the problem is about classic C arrays, size is unknown and it's not the best solution in my eye. Besides, with ARC on, I can't use objects in C structs.

So I thought of using Objects. Why program fully in Objective C, I like that idea. My header would then be a class looking like that :

```
@interface PcapHeader : NSObject
@property (readwrite, strong) NSData *mac_dst;
@property (readwrite, strong) NSData *mac_src;
@property (readwrite, strong) NSData *tag;
@property (readwrite, strong) NSData *ethertype;
@property (readwrite, strong) NSData *crc;
@end
```

I want to use a similar format for all headers to simplify the code that comes later.

But I'm new to objective-c so here i have a lot of questions. 1) Is it okay to use NSData as I do it above, which is to contain only a few bytes. I feel like it's not optimized AT ALL. 2) Should I use properties here or instance variables are more appropriate ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to use NSData for your properties. 
You could use C types. 
For C arrays, you just need to store an int of the count of elements. This is common practice in C data structures and C functions. This count can be a struct member or a property in an object. 
You could also use NSValue or NSNumber to box the C types into objects that can be used in Objective-C collections like NSArray. 
As for optimizations, build it first, then determine if it is sufficiently optimized. 
Objects much like scripting languages will tend to introduce some overhead, but it is almost always a waste of time to optimize first. 
NSData is not a heavy class. Objective-C objects are really glorified structs themselves.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. What I did is I simply used C types in the middle of my Objective-C classes and it doesn't really bother me anymore.

Comment: Your other friend should become NSValue